# Dropwizard ScheduledReporter rate unit

Tags: dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard Meters to report rates of an event. I am somewhat confused by the unit conversion that seems to happen during reporting.
As a test, I recorded one event, using SlidingWindowMoving average.

I'd expect that the 1-min rate will show 1 event/minute.
What I do observe though is that SlidingTimeWindowMovingAverages.getM1Rate() produces 1, but the CSV reporter multiplies by 60 (from ScheduledReporter.convertRate) if I started it with

```
 CsvReporter.forRegistry(getRegistry(registryName))
                .formatFor(Locale.US)
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build(metricsPath);
```

Starting it without .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.MINUTES) does indeed report 1 but rate_unit is `events/second`.

My question is -- if 1 event occurred inside the last minute, why is events/minute reported as 60? Is there a way to configure the reporter so we truly get the number of events inside that time window?